# Webview Not Working in Fragment Android Studio

Tags: android, webview, fragment

I've tried everything, My View won't work in my `Fragment` Can anyone assist me

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout. fragment_one, container, false);
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: what's issue?Have you added fragment in activity

Comment: post the xml layout

Comment: don't forgot add permission in manifest file **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`**

Comment: I did add the permission to the Manifest file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override onViewCreated method in your fragment and call `mWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");`

Answer (score 0):

Do this :-

```
    mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    // Enable Javascript


    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
```

For more basic details you can take guide from these links:-

- https://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial-android/fragment-in-android-tutorial-with-example-using-webview-291
- https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/03/android-fragment-tutorial-webview-example.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewFragment.html

Comment: I just tried Copy and pasted this but now the mWebView is showing up red and its saying "Cannot Ressolve Symbol"

Comment: @J.Tulloch  can you share your teamviewer details